# Is it just me, or does Firebase's default LIMIT() behavior work backwards?

Tags: firebase

This is not a big deal, but I wanted to throw it out there - if you had 100 items with incremental priorities, you would have a list like this:

```
item#1: { .priority: 1 }
...
item#100: { .priority: 100 }
```

The first item is #1 with priority 1, and the last item is #100 with priority 100. Now if you LIMIT() the list to 3 items, like this:

```
firebaseRef.limit(3).once(...)
```

Rather than being returned items 1-3, you would be returned items 97-100. Do most people expect that? It's the opposite of how limits generally work in other environments. In SQL for example, you start at the beginning of the set and stop when you hit the limit.

Now this isn't a technical limitation or anything (I believe), because we can actually get records 1-3 pretty easily by using STARTAT() on the first item:

```
firebaseRef.startAt(1).limit(3).once(...)
```

In fact, when LIMIT() is used without STARTAT() or ENDAT() it actually behaves like you specified ENDAT() with the last item. For example these produce the same results:

```
firebaseRef.limit(3).once(...)
firebaseRef.endAt(100).limit(3).once(...)
```

Doesn't it seem like the default behavior should be to mimic STARTAT() from the first position, rather than ENDAT() from the last position, if only LIMIT() is specified?

Answer (score 3):

You are absolutely right in concluding that the default behavior works as if `endAt()` was used (and thus the latest items will be returned). This is because in the most common use cases you'd want to display the latest data, not the oldest; eg: chat history or notifications.